# Third party sources disabled

Tags: 18.04, updates, 19.10

I want to upgrade from `Ubuntu18.04` to  `Ubuntu19.10` but I got this error message.

**Question:**
What should I do to fix this issue and What is the root of the problem?

> Third-party sources disabled
>
> Some third-party entries in your sources.list were disabled. You can re-enable them after the upgrade with the 'software-properties' tool or your package manager.

Thanks

Comment: Upgrades are tested only with Ubuntu sourced software (many 3rd parties use non-Ubuntu compatible versions to ensure their versions replace the default Ubuntu ones; this creates problems with the release-upgrade process). Ubuntu 18.04 is only officially tested to upgrade to 18.10 (the next release) and will be tested again before 20.04.1 is released (ie. the next LTS release).  Upgrades from 18.04 to 19.04 or 19.10 are **not** tested as unsupported (*possible yeah, but it's for you to test & fix any issues*)  You add back what gets disabled **if** you need it (pointing at eoan, not bionic)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable your third-party software sources:

1. Open `Ubuntu Software Centre`.
2. Go to `Edit` > `Software Sources` > `Other Software`
3. Re-check all your sources that you want to be re-enabled by using 
   the command `sudo apt update`

Comment: Is there a way to do this via Bash?