# I failed to update to the new LTS release and appear to have messed up the OS

Tags: boot, updates, hard-drive, bios, boot-repair

A little over a week ago I updated my Ubuntu server from Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. I use AnyDesk to remote control the server because of access issues. I initiated the update, input my credentials, and at some point lost my connection while it was updating. I noticed it mentioned that it would disable third-party software which would include AnyDesk so I left it to come back at a later day when I could get physical access to the server.

I was going to follow this step-by-step if everything had gone properly.

Server fix [Third party sources disabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192864/third-party-sources-disabled)

To enable your third-party software sources:

- Open Ubuntu Software Centre.
- Go to Edit > Software Sources > Other Software
- Re-check all your sources that you want to be re-enabled by using the command sudo apt update

In hindsight I may have messed up big time and accidentally powered down the server during the update. Now I can't even boot into Ubuntu and I don't think it recognizes my drives. [I was able to get this screen photo.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpPWT.jpg)

| Component | Selection |
| --- | --- |
| CPU | Intel Core i7-4790K 4 GHz Quad-Core Processor |
| Motherboard | Gigabyte GA-Z97-HD3 ATX LGA1150 Motherboard |
| Memory | Crucial Ballistix Sport 16 GB (2 x 8 GB) DDR3-1600 CL9 Memory |
| Storage | Samsung 850 Evo 250 GB 2.5" Solid State Drive |
| Storage | Seagate Barracuda Compute 8 TB 3.5" 5400RPM Internal Hard Drive |
| Storage | Seagate Barracuda Compute 8 TB 3.5" 5400RPM Internal Hard Drive |
| Storage | Seagate Barracuda Compute 8 TB 3.5" 5400RPM Internal Hard Drive |
| Video Card | PNY Quadro P1000 4 GB Video Card |
| Case | Rosewill R​SV-R4100 |
| Power Supply | Silverstone Strider Titanium 600 W 80+ Titanium Certified Fully Modular ATX Power Supply |
| Wireless Network Adapter | Gigabyte GC-WB867D-I REV 4.2 802.11a/b/g/n/ac PCIe x1 Wi-Fi Adapter |

Does anyone have advice for how to recover?

Comment: start by booting to a live USB, chrooting into the partition, and re-running the upgrade

Comment: Should I use Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS or Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS for the live USB? Or does it not matter?